# Binding params and escaping string in MySQLi (PHP)

Tags: php, data-binding, mysqli, bind

I bind all variables to all kind of statements (`UPDATE`/`INSERT`/`SELECT` etc.) using the `bind_param()` function. But I am confused with bind params.

Do I also need to use **real_escape_string** even though I use bind_param? Are both of them completely different things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you don't need to escape them. Binding params eliminates the need for escaping by removing the dangers of string concatenation.

With binding, you're essentially telling MySQL to *use the contents of this variable as the value for this field.*